# Can I connect my Android device to a laptop via WiFi to use file sharing?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi

How can I connect my *Sony Xperia U* to my laptop using WiFi to use file sharing?
I tried normal connectivity by sharing my laptop WiFi and connect my *Xperia U* to the laptop -- but it only accesses the internet, not the file sharing.

What should I do to access file sharing and managing my laptop using my phone? Is there any application, setting, or procedure that can help me connect my laptop and my phone?

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of solutions available here. Depending on which device you want to work (i.e. using your Android device to push things to/pull things from your laptop, or working on your laptop and accessing the Android device), your choices may differ, though:

[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) is a file manager app for Android which also can access remote resources via WiFi. Amongst others, it supports CIFS (aka "Windows Shares") and FTP.

[image: ES File Explorer]
<sup>ES File Explorer (Source: Google Play)</sup>

[AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) is an app running on Android, and offering access via web browser. So you can work from your laptop and access your Android device via a web interface.

[image: AirDroid]
<sup>Airdroid (source: Google Play)</sup>

Both variants require your Android device and your laptop being in the same network (well, there are ways around this restriction — but this is how it definitly works). Using the same WiFi access point for both should guarantee that, for example.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tutorial how you share your files from Android to PC or PC to Android using Wi-Fi... No need to use AirDroid or WifiFileShare... http://youtu.be/WLBRsIa_4aU

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies – and it might already be for those not able to connect to Youtube because of firewalls. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).