# How to connect a PC and android?

Tags: wlan

I wanted to share files between my computer and android device but always connecting them with a cable is a trouble. Is there a way to use my phone's WLAN network and my PC's WLAN to do this(without any internet connection), kind of like how Filetransfer software works on two android devices? 
The file transfer software that I mention of only ranges for a short distance for android devices, I just want to use the two WLAN networks of my PC and android devices to share files between PC and my device and use no internet resources at all since the network here is not so good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I connect my Android device to a laptop via WiFi to use file sharing?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49212/can-i-connect-my-android-device-to-a-laptop-via-wifi-to-use-file-sharing)

Answer (score 1):

There are many File Transfer Software available for Android which can transfer file wirelessly between PC and android phone, some of the most popular applications are listed below. The steps to establish a connection are very simple and given in these application only, but for Xender I have enlisted all the steps for better understanding.

> ### Zapya
>
> Download Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dewmobile.kuaiya.play&hl=en

> ### SHAREit
>
> Download Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en

> ### Xender
>
> This is my personal favorite and steps to connect the smartphone to PC are enlisted below.

1. Download: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender in your smartphone.
2. Open Xender and Click on Floating Action Button.[image: Xender App]
3. Select PC/Mac in Transfer to/from screen.
4. Click on Create Hotspot.[image: Create Hotspot]
5. Now the application will create a hotspot in your smartphone and name of the hotspot will be presented in next screen.
6. Follow the onscreen steps on your phone to connect it to the PC which will be:

   - Connect PC to Wi-Fi network "Name of hotspot"
   - Open web Browser in your PC
   - Enter the web address which is displayed on your phone.
7. You have connected the phone to the PC and now you can start transferring photos, music, files etc.

> ### Zapya WebShare
>
> This is specifically for File Transfer between PC and smartphone only. It also allows to control Camera and display android notifications and messages in PC's Web Browser.
>   Download Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dewmobile.kuaiya.web&hl=en